# How to know the status of an already established connection?

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming, communication

I have seen a few questions relating to this but never encountered the solution that is feasible my situation. I have 2 communicating devices communicating through my proxy device. I want to know how I can periodically check for the status of the connection. The proxy programs are in java. The methods isClosed() and etc will not serve this purpose. I have found out that reading from the stream is not so effective (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne.aspx) and doing a write on the bufferedstreams may be effective. But my constraint is that the actual client and the servers are untouchable (the C code of the communication part cannot be changed). So I want to know if there is an alternative way to check for the lost connection.

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the protocol followed by the applications, you might be able to send an ECHO test or something just like it that has no impact with will tell you if the connection is still functional.  There might be a "version" command or something that you could use.

Comment: reading should be enough if you want to be notified of a keepalive timeout the OS detected.

Answer (score 0):

A socket can not know what happens between its local and remote endpoints, not without some sort of communication to establish if there really is a valid connection between the endpoints. The only way to know if a connection is alive is to use some sort of *ping* message that the application on the other end will reply to. That *ping* message can actually be any kind of message, like polling for data or any other message that can be sent without causing secondary effects.

If you can't change the code of the other application, is there any message you can send regularly to see if the connection is alive?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem recently and came to the conclusion that the cleanest solution would be to send "empty" TCP packets, that is, packets with a payload length of 0. This would cause the other end's TCP stack to simply send an ACK without ever notifying the application on the other side, which again allows the local TCP stack to determine if the connection is still alive.

Unfortunately, Java (Sun/Oracle SDK) does not provide any means to send empty packets; `write(new byte[0]);` will not work.

In my case, I seem to have found a possible solution:

[sendUrgentData()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#sendUrgentData%28int%29) can be used to transmit a single byte of "urgent" or ["out of band"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Out_of_band_data) data. This kind of TCP packet is simply ignored by my peer's software, does therefore not interfere with any other "normal" data on the connection, and does allow my local TCP stack to detect connection failure.

Considering that the "OOB" data is rarely ever used and sometimes implemented only half way -as it is in Java-, it seems likely that using this "trick" will not interfere with most applications.

I did not persue this approach beyond some simple testing (used another way of "keep alives" in the end) but it may help you solve your issue. It's definitely worth a try.

Comment: Noticing what others have posted: You actually do not need the other end to actively send back anything to determine if the connection is still alive. It is sufficient to be able to *send* any data to the other end without breaking the application's protocol. TCP's ACKs will do the rest for you.

Comment: This assumes the application ignores OOB data... Applications can read OOB data inline (SO_OOBINLINE), in which case the OOB data would be mixed (though returned by different recv calls) with the normal data.

Comment: It won't work to a Java recipient because OOB data is received inline in Java.

Comment: @EJP: True only **if** you explicitly [setOOBInline( true )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setOOBInline%28boolean%29) (defaults to false) before...

Comment: OK. If you set it to false you won't receive OOB data at all in Java.